# Send multiple data for one checkbox by ajax without submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I create checkbox form sql 
 /and want to send data by click checkbox
/ but data not send.

this is my checkbox loop

```
<ul>
    <?php while($objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery)){
    ?>
        <li>
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="cb<?php echo $objResult["mid"] ?>" 
            onclick="save_checkbox(<?php echo $objResult["mid"] ?>,<?php echo $objResult["mpass"] ?>,date('Y-m-d'));"/>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

ajax function

```
<script>
    function save_checkbox(mission_id, record_check, date) {
        $.post('ASEngine/ASCheckpass.php', {
            mid : mission_id,
            check : record_check,
            date : date
        }, function(response) {
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
            $("[id ^='cb']").html(response);
        });
    }
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$mid = $_POST["mid"];
$check = $_POST["check"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
//query
?>
```

I can't send data to my php
Help me please..

Comment: You have to set a `name` for your checkbox.

Comment: You need to quote your non-number values in the call to `save_checkbox()`.

Comment: You dont need a name on the checkbox when js is taking control of the click action and using what is passed to the function.

Comment: Also with what @PatrickQ mentioned, `date('Y-m-d')` is missing php tags around it.

Comment: When debugging Javascript/AJAX issues, your first step should be to check your browser's Javascript console for errors.  If there are, research them if necessary and address them.  If not, check the Network tab to inspect both the request and response to make sure they are what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some HTML changes required in your code:

Quotes over parameters and one PHP script tag wrapper at `date` function

```
<ul>
    <?php while($objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery)){
    ?>
        <li>
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="cb<?php echo $objResult["mid"] ?>" 
            onclick="save_checkbox('<?php echo $objResult["mid"] ?>','<?php echo $objResult["mpass"] ?>','<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>');"/>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```